# Incorrect Slider scaling in C#

Tags: c#, slider, max

My problem is an odd one. I have a setup where a slider can be dragged to change the value of an number. The slider's range goes from 0 to 24 at the moment. The user can alter the scale of the slider with a 'scale' button. The 'scale' button simply multiplies the value obtained from the slider. The user can also incrementally increase or decrease the value with a '+' and a '-' button. All ok so far.

But I wanted to try actually changing the slider.Maximum property. This is so when the user changes the scale of the range of the slider, the slider position will move to accurately reflect the new number on the larger scale. However, when I try to alter the slider.Maximum property, I get all sorts of odd results.

So my slider's current range is 0 - 24. If I try, say,

```
Slider.Maximum += 5;
```

the range of the slider changes from 0 - 32. Then if I call that function again, it changes from 0 - 42.

I have no idea why it's doing this. Can anyone help me make sense of this?

Regards,

-AT.

Comment: Are you positive that the maximum is really changing from 24 to 32 on that line? If you debug into it and check the value of Slider.Maximum before and after the line of code you show, is that really what you're seeing? If it is, I'm intrigued!

Comment: Hi Tim. When I remove that line, there's no problem with the scaling. In fact, the incremental increasing and decreasing recognise the proper maximum value, as does a text box outputting what should be the maximum range. For some reason, the slider itself just fails to.

http://imgur.com/a/rn1SH

Comment: This might be totally offbase, but looking at those screenshots, it looks like it might have to do with your multiplier. In the second screenshot, you've added 3, and the multiplier is 1.2. ( 24 + 3 ) * 1.2 = 32 (truncated). In the third, you've added 3 again and the multiplier is 1.4. (24 + 3 + 3) * 1.4 = 42. Maybe?

Comment: I didn't think I'd used my 'scale' number to affect that range, but the number add up so perfectly there must be something going on. I'll look at it now and report back. (Thanks for the help so far!)

Comment: Bingo! I took it out of that function and put it in a new, blank one, and bam! It works like expected now. Thanks a bunch, Tim!

Comment: Great! Want to go ahead and add your screenshot into the question and I'll move my comment to be an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at those screenshots, it looks like it might have to do with your multiplier.

In the second screenshot, you've added 3, and the scale is 1.2.

( 24 + 3 ) * 1.2 = 32 (truncated)

In the third, you've added 3 again and the scale is 1.4.

(24 + 3 + 3) * 1.4 = 42

So somehow your scale is impacting the slider, even though I can't quite see where in the small chunk of code in your screenshot.

Comment: You were right. I still don't know where exactly it was happening, but moving it out of that button class cleared the problem right up.